Are supertypes of a type just the ones that are directly extended or implemented?
For example ArrayList extends AbstractList and implements List, RandomAccess, Cloneable, Serializable. Are these the only supertypes or do we also mean AbstractCollection and Object are supertypes of Arraylis?
I am currently having a class for JAVA and working on a project. Among other things I need to find the types of the program that has the most supertypes using Reflecion API. I need to know if I must include "indirect" supertypes.

If this is a school assignment, ask your teacher. I would argue that you need to go up to object.

According to the Java Language Specification, supertypes include "indirect" ones, but if you are doing this for a class, it might be better to ask your teacher/instructor for clarification. Because if you are using the definition in the Java Language Specification, some types can potentially have an infinite number of supertypes. The supertype of List<? super Object> for example. includes List<? super T> for all reference types T.

Note further that “the types of the program” is ambiguous too. Ask for clarification whether the types of the libraries included in the runtime of the program also count. In Java, types can be added at runtime or even created on the fly. Therefore, the Reflection API has no way to enumerate all existing types. So, the task of finding types meeting a specific criteria needs a well defined limitation of the types to check.

according Java Language Specification 4.10. Subtyping there is a distinction between supertype and direct supertype: "The supertypes of a type are obtained by reflexive and transitive closure over the direct supertype relation, written S >₁ T, which is defined by rules given later in this section. We write S :> T to indicate that the supertype relation holds between S and T." (and there is also a proper supertype)

I think it's a matter of whose terminology you are referring to as there's no universally accepted definition; however, I would say that indirect supertypes are certainly supertypes. For example, you might write a class MyList implements List. Then later you decide to extend AbstractList. You keep the same behaviour of MyList but the fact it now extends AbstractList is an implementation detail. MyList is still a subtype of List. (In this definition, I'm using "type" to refer to both interfaces and classes.)
